# How to sort a table in php and keep table sorted after Posting the PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I have tried several methods to sort a table and keep it sorted , but all those that i found they return the sorting to the original format of the page after i  'POST' the page or refresh it...

My question is this Is there any way to sort my table and keep it sorted after a page refresh or Post . Any ideas ?

This is my index.php where i call to Post my ajax.php every 1 second

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var timer = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loaddata() { $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'ajax.php', dataType: 'html', success: function(data) { $('#load').html(data); setTimeout(loaddata, timer); }}); }
    loaddata();
});
</script>
```

and this is my ajax.php where i make a table using echo

```
    <table class="tablestyle1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="120" align="center" class="title">Balance</td>
<td width="120" align="center" class="title">Ewuity</td>
<td width="120" align="center" class="title">Used</td>
<td width="120" align="center" class="title">Usable</td>
<td width="120" align="center" class="title">Gross</td>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[0][0]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[0][1]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[0][2]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[0][3] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[0][4]; ?></td>
<tr>
<td align="center" <?php colorize3($csv2[1][0], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[1][0]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorize3($csv2[1][1], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[1][1]; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $csv2[1][2]; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $csv2[1][3]; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $csv2[1][4]; ?></td>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[4][0]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[4][1]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[4][2]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[4][3] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $csv2[4][4]; ?></td>
<tr>
<td align="center" <?php colorize4($csv2[5][0], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[5][0]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorize4($csv2[5][1], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[5][1]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorize4($csv2[5][2], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[5][2]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorize4($csv2[5][3], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[5][3]; ?></td>
<td align="center" <?php colorize4($csv2[5][4], true); ?>><?php echo $csv2[5][4]; ?></td>
</tr></tr></tr></tr></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it works about like that ...

where `fieldName` would be the field to sort by and `sortOrder` would be either `ASC` or `DESC`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',

    data: {
        sortBy: fieldName,
        sortOrder: sortOrder
    },

    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#load').html(data);
        setTimeout(loaddata, timer);
    }
});
```

the values of these two post-fields would go into the `ORDER BY` conditions of the SQL query.